# Is Scala mixin really better than multiple C++ inheritance?

Tags: oop, scala, traits

People say C++ inheritance is evil, so Java 'fixed' this problem with interface.

But Scala introduced `trait`s, they're... interface with partial implementation? Doesn't this brought multiple inheritance back?

Does it mean Scala guys think multiple inheritance is good? Or They have some critical differences I haven't noticed?

Comment: Please, take a look at [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6) book, page 258, §12.6. I found this explanation extremely good and might try to rephrase it, but I wouldn't -- it is hard to write something more comprehensive than that. In short, in Scala there is no so called [*diamond problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) (that exists in C++ and that is why C++ multiple inheritance was critisized so badly), because of lack of constructors, well defined method invokation order and different notion of *super*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The worst part of multiple inheritance is diamond inheritance, where a subclass has two or more paths to the same parent somewhere up the chain.  This creates ambiguity if implementations differ along the two paths (i.e. are overridden from the original implementation).  In C++ the solution is particularly ugly: you embed both incompatible parent classes and have to specify when you call which implementation you want.  This is confusing, creates extra work at every call site (or, more likely, forces you to override explicitly and state the one you want; this manual work is tedious and introduces a chance for error), and can lead to objects being larger than they ought to be.

Scala solves some but not all of the problems by limiting multiple inheritance to traits.  Because traits have no constructors, the final class can *linearize* the inheritance tree, which is to say that even though two parents on a path back to a common super-parent nominally are both parents, one is the "correct" one, namely the one listed last.  This scheme would leave broken half-initialized classes around if you could have (completely generic) constructors, but as it is, you don't have to embed the class twice, and at the use site you can ignore how much inheritance if any has happened.  It does not, however, make it that much easier to reason about what will happen when you layer many traits on top of each other, and if you inherit from both `B` and `C`, you can't choose to take *some* of `B`'s implementations and the some of `C`'s.

So it's better in that it addresses some of the most serious criticisms of the C++ model.  Whether it is better enough is a matter of taste; plenty of people even like the taste of C++'s multiple inheritance well enough to use it.

Comment: I'd rather specify the ambiguous members explicitly than rely on a rule that makes non-obvious choices.

Comment: @joeytwiddle - I just noticed that you caught my error over a year and a half ago!  Fixed the text.

Comment: @nclark - You won't get the non-obvious choices unless you're already overriding, so there is _some_ protection against non-obvious choices.  But once you have already overloaded in both branches, yeah, the last one listed is chosen automatically, and one could argue that being explicit then too would be better.  (If only to specify which superclass implementation you want.)